# How to get count of all user patches?

Tags: gerrit, wikimedia

I went through the api [doc](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/rest-api.html) to get the data from it. I want to get the details of count of all the commits that a user made with the username. Is there any possible way to perform it. I tried searching many of the API's but I could not find a suitable one. Is there any API to get the count of all commits of a specific user? if not then how to perform it?

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the Gerrit repositories in the Gerrit server (GERRIT_SITE/git) you can get what you want executing the following command inside an specific repository (GERRIT_SITE/git/REPO_FULL_PATH):

```
git log --pretty="format:%ae" --since="2019-01-01 00:00:00" --until="2019-12-31 23:59:59" --all | cut -d '@' -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -k 1,1nr -k 2,2
    410 aaaaa
    169 bbbbb
    128 ccccc
     22 ddddd
     19 eeeee
     ...
```

Explanation:

```
--pretty="format:%ae" => Show only the committer e-mail
--since and --utill   => Limit the search
cut -d '@' -f 1       => Remove the "@DOMAIN" from the e-mail address
sort                  => Sort by user name
uniq -c               => Omit repeated user names, prefixing users by the number of occurrences
sort -k 1,1nr -k 2,2  => Sort by number of occurrences then by user name
```

Comment: Is it not possible with the api (instead of using ```git```)?

Comment: It is possible but It will be very much difficult to achieve.

Comment: I have searched most of their docs but could not find any api's to perform it. If there is a way to get the count, can you please tell me how to perform it?

Comment: You'll need to query for changes (https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes) and then process the result to find out who is the owner of the change to sum up the total.

Comment: Is it possible to get the commits only after a specific create date?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Is there any possible way to get all the user changesets for a specific span (based on created date of the changesent) in gerrit?

Comment: I don't think so. You'll need to get all changes from the user and then, locally, process only the changes in the specific span.